# how a field marked as 'editable=False' work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

When a field is marked as 'editable=False' in the model, it will not appear on the generated form. How is the field initialized and saved into database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By you, in python code. For example, if your object had a non-editable `user` field:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    myobj = form.save(commit=False)
    myobj.user = request.user
    myobj.save()
```